# How to display name,title in ListView, but only Employee No.in SingleListItem?

Tags: android, listview, listitem

I have successfully produced a ListView, which takes JSON data from a remote MySQL database, and adds the 3 fields (employee no, employee name, and title) to an Output string called
"employees".
This displays on an Android phone, OK, but what I really want to do is display ONLY employee
name and title - and then when this record in the list is clicked on, the I want to display
ONLY employee no in the next Activity.
Using Split String, I have managed to just show "employee no" in the next Activity, but that
still leaves the problem of just showing employee name + title ONLY in the ListView.
If I only add those 2 fields together in the Output string, then "employee no" would be 
"invisible" when single item clicked on..
Many thanks in advance!
Here is the relevent code in my MainActivity..

```
    for (int i = 0; i < jsonMainNode.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject jsonChildNode = jsonMainNode.getJSONObject(i);
    String name = jsonChildNode.optString("employee name");
    String number = jsonChildNode.optString("employee no");
    String title = jsonChildNode.optString("title");
    String outPut = name + "-" + title + "-" + number;
    employeeList.add(createEmployee("employees", outPut)); 
   }

  } catch (JSONException e) {
   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error" + e.toString(),
     Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  }

  SimpleAdapter simpleAdapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, employeeList,
    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_activated_1,
    new String[] { "employees" }, new int[] { android.R.id.text1 });
  listView.setAdapter(simpleAdapter);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to create an object of Employee which has three fields

```
private String emplyeeName;
private String employeeTitle;
private String employeeNum;
```

Then fill an ArrayList with the data returned from the server, and populate it using a Custom Adapter.
This way you could manage what should appear in the listview item.

hope it'll help. If there is something not obvious do not hesitate to ask. :)

Edit 1:

Here is an example :

The code in onCreate in MainActivity

```
final ArrayList<Employee> arr = new ArrayList<Employee>();

    final ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, final int position, long id) {

            String EmployeeNum = arr.get(position).getEmployeeNum();

            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
            i.putExtra("EmployeeNum", EmployeeNum);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });


    CustomAdapter adapter = new CustomAdapter(this , R.layout.activity_main , arr);
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);
```

The custom adapter

```
public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Employee> {

ArrayList<Employee> Info;
private Context context;

CustomAdapter(Context context, int resource, ArrayList<Employee> objects) {
    super(context, resource, objects);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    this.context = context;
    Info = objects;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    EmployeeItemHolder employeeHolder;
    View view = convertView;
    if (view == null) {
        employeeHolder = new EmployeeItemHolder();
        LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_row, parent, false);

        employeeHolder.title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvtextView);


        view.setTag(employeeHolder);
    } else {
        employeeHolder = (EmployeeItemHolder) view.getTag();

    }

    Employee eItem = (Employee) this.Info.get(position);
    employeeHolder.title.setText(eItem.getEmployeeTitle()+"-"+eItem.getEmplyeeName());

    return view;
}

private static class EmployeeItemHolder {
    TextView title;
}
}
```

custom_row.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:text="Medium Text"
    android:id="@+id/tvtextView" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Edit 2:

To integrate with this code convert your employeeList from

```
ArrayList<String>
```

to

```
ArrayList<Employee>
```

Here is an example :

```
ArrayList<Employee> employeeList = new ArrayList<Employee>();
    for (int i = 0; i < jsonMainNode.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject jsonChildNode = jsonMainNode.getJSONObject(i);
        Employee emp = new Employee();
        emp.setEmplyeeName(jsonChildNode.optString("employee name"));
        emp.setEmployeeTitle(jsonChildNode.optString("title"));
        emp.setEmployeeNum(jsonChildNode.optString("employee no"));

        employeeList.add(emp); 
    }

} catch (JSONException e) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error" + e.toString(),
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
CustomAdapter adapter = new CustomAdapter(this, R.layout.activity_main, employeeList );
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

hope that'll help you

Comment: Hi! Thanks for great answer - but I'm not sure how to integrate this into my existing JSON-parsing code. Any chance I could send you my existing code for MainActivity?

Comment: see the second edit .. If there are any problems don't hesitate to ask.